# Why UIButton's selector method is not called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

My iPhone has iOS8. I'd like to add DONE button on the `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`. DONE is displayed on the left side empty button. But the selector method `doneButtonClicked` is not called when I touch(press) DONE. My code is below. What is wrong with the code?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animtated {

    // Register the observer for the keyboardWillShow event
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animtated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // create custom button

    if (!self.doneButton)
    {
        self.doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [self.doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }

    self.doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [self.doneButton setTitle:@"DONE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.doneButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]];
    [self.doneButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.doneButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    // locate keyboard view
    if ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count] <= 1) return;
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard;
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard found, add the button
        if ([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
        {
            BOOL isPortrait = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation);
            self.doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(((isPortrait)?0:-1),((int) (keyboard.frame.size.height*3)/4) + ((isPortrait)?0:1),(int) keyboard.frame.size.width/3-1, (isPortrait)?60:40);
            [keyboard addSubview:self.doneButton];
        }
        //This code will work on iOS 8.0
        else if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetContainerView"] == YES)
        {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < [keyboard.subviews count] ; i++)
            {
                UIView* hostkeyboard = [keyboard.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
                if([[hostkeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetHost"] == YES)
                {
                    BOOL isPortrait = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation);
                    self.doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(((isPortrait) ? 0 : -1),((int) (hostkeyboard.frame.size.height*3)/4) + ((isPortrait) ? 0 : 1),(int) hostkeyboard.frame.size.width/3-1, (isPortrait) ? 60 : 40);
                    [hostkeyboard addSubview:self.doneButton];
                }
            }
        }
        else{}
    }
}

- (void)doneButtonClicked:(id)sender{
    [self.heightUpdateTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: due to this condition `if (!self.doneButton)`. The target may not be set . self.doneButton may be an IBOutlet r initialised before `keyboardWillShow` del gets called , so that the condition is always false.

Comment: No i run line by line the target is set. I declare as @property UIButton *doneButton; in .h file.

Comment: ok, let me know at wt event, U'r initialising the `doneButton`?

Comment: According to this tutorial (http://www.guilmo.com/how-to-create-a-uibutton-programmatically/), there are all what I need, i think. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to run the code with keeping the addtarget instruction after the "if(!self.doneButton)"

Comment: @channi, yes I tried just now. Still selector method is not called. I commented out if(!self.doneButton).

Comment: hey, i was just tried your code , its working like a charm... after a little bit changes.

Comment: @SubhashSharma, what is a little bit change? what is your iOS version?

Comment: ios version 8 , xcode 6.1 .. check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. This method works for me for iOS 6, 7 & 8:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)iNotification
    // If there's no keyboard yet, don't do anything
    if ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count] < 2) {
        return;
    }

    UIWindow *keyboardWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows][1];

    // Create new dismiss keyboard button
    UIButton *aDismissKeyboardButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.3")) {
        aDismissKeyboardButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 53, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / 3, 53);
    } else {
        aDismissKeyboardButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
    }

    aDismissKeyboardButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = FALSE;
    [aDismissKeyboardButton setExclusiveTouch:YES];

    UIImage *aDismissKeyboardButtonImageNormal;
    UIImage *aDismissKeyboardButtonImageHighlighted;

    aDismissKeyboardButtonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
    aDismissKeyboardButtonImageHighlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageHighLighted.png"];

    [aDismissKeyboardButton setImage:aDismissKeyboardButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aDismissKeyboardButton setImage:aDismissKeyboardButtonImageHighlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    SEL aDoneButtonSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"doneButtonPressed");
    [aDismissKeyboardButton addTarget:iDelegate action:aDoneButtonSelector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    // Locate keyboard view and add button
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.3")) {
        for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
            if ([[window description] hasPrefix:@"<UITextEffectsWindow"]) {
                [window addSubview:aDismissKeyboardButton];
                return;
            }
        }
    } else if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
        for (UIView *aSubview in [[keyboardWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews]) {
            if ([[aSubview description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetHost"]) {
                [aSubview addSubview:aDismissKeyboardButton];
                return;
            }
        }
    } else {
        NSString *keyboardPrefix = SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0") ? @"<UIPeripheralHost" : @"<UIKeyboard";

        for (UIView *aSubView in keyboardWindow.subviews) {
            if ([[aSubView description] hasPrefix:keyboardPrefix]) {
                [aSubView addSubview:aDismissKeyboardButton];
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I have defined a macro to check system version like this:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

Comment: Please post a reason for down voting. This solution works flawlessly for me.

Answer (score 0):

`sorry for bad english`.

I was copied your code earlier to check, what the mistake, after few changes its working good But the `Frame of done Button` is deferent tha t you can change according to your desire, let check edited code..

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animtated {

    // Register the observer for the keyboardWillShow event
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animtated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // create custom button


     UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [doneButton setTitle:@"DONE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]];
    [doneButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    // locate keyboard view
    if ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count] <= 1) return;
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard;
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard found, add the button
        if ([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
        {
            BOOL isPortrait = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation);
            doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(((isPortrait)?0:-1),((int) (keyboard.frame.size.height*3)/4) + ((isPortrait)?0:1),(int) keyboard.frame.size.width/3-1, (isPortrait)?60:40);
            [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        }
        //This code will work on iOS 8.0
        else if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetContainerView"] == YES)
        {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < [keyboard.subviews count] ; i++)
            {
                UIView* hostkeyboard = [keyboard.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
                if([[hostkeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetHost"] == YES)
                {
                    BOOL isPortrait = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation);
                    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(((isPortrait) ? 0 : -1),((int) (hostkeyboard.frame.size.height*3)/4) + ((isPortrait) ? 0 : 1),(int) hostkeyboard.frame.size.width/3-1, (isPortrait) ? 60 : 40);
                    [hostkeyboard addSubview:doneButton];
                }
            }
        }
        else{}
    }
}

- (void)doneButtonClicked:(id)sender{
    [self->cityTxt resignFirstResponder]; //cityTxt is my textfield
}
```

its work for me, hope it works for you also.